# Does Gmail still have the option to import email from other email accounts?

Tags: gmail

I recall there was an option in Gmail email settings to import emails from another email account but I no longer see it.

Is this option still available?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

1. Go to **Mail settings**
2. Go to **Accounts and Import**
3. You have the **Import mail and contacts** option

[image]

Comment: HOLY COW.  I looked 18 times and didn't see it!

Answer (score 2):

If this does not work for a specific provider you can always use [Mozilla Thunderbird](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird) to import mail between different services and set up a filter to move or copy incoming messages from the old account to new one.